# Selenium - Window focus issues in Chrome browser when my VM is minimized

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, window, focus, minimized

1. I Connected to VM by RemoteDesktop
2. Triggered Chrome browser (latest Version 66.0.3359.139) through Selenium - Java
3. Launch the login page (which has UserName and Password fields in it). Put some hard sleep for 5 seconds
4. Minimize my window for VM before script enters UserName or Password
5. I got an issue, Unable to enter UserName and Password after Step 4 where the script fails. I observed it like Chrome lost its focus when I minimize the VM window and this is causing the issue

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Why do you want to `Minimize my window for VM before script enters UserName or Password`?

Comment: I want to clarify myself again, I just minimize VM (RDP) window here as I have only one monitor with me. There the script running in VM fails as unable to focus on Chrome browser..